# Updating Household address when Contact address changes? (Nonprofit Starter Pack)

Tags: nonprofit-starter-pack

When I create a Contact without assigning a Household, a Household is magically created for me using the Contact's info to seed the data. Huzzah! This is exactly what I want.

However, when I update the Contact's address information, the Household address info doesn't change. I would like the Household address to be updated when a Household member's address changes. (Maybe only when the member's "Home" address changes, but not strictly necessary.)

- Can this be accomplished easily?
- Is this a terrible idea?
- What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the delayed response, I just came across your post.  One tip if you're looking for help on the NPSP is to use the Power of Us Hub at powerofus.salesforcefoundation.org to ask your questions.  The Hub is a Salesforce Community which is where most of the Foundation's customers ask questions and get answers.  You'll find a lot more people there who are familiar with the NPSP than you will here.

As for your question, the current NPSP has a Copy Address to Household button you can add to contact layouts in order to sync the address.  However, that doesn't address the automated functionality you're looking for.

The good news is that NPSP 3.0 is due for release very soon and includes a completely new way of handling accounts and households: Household Accounts.  While you can still use the bucket and 1:1 account model in 3.0, the new Household Accounts model will give you what you're looking for if you make the switch.

With Household Accounts, Addresses are now their own object and related to the Household.  All Contacts in the Household automatically get their address fields updated from the default address of the Household unless they have an override address (i.e. someone in the household needs a different address than the household).

If you edit the main address field on a Contact who is using the Household's default address, the Household's default address is automatically updated and populated to all other Contacts in the Household who use the default address.

There's also some other functionality such as support for seasonal addresses (i.e. at summer home from 7/1 to 9/15) and automatic address verification and validation via an integration with SmartyStreet which is free for nonprofits.